# NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml when generating sitemap.xml django website

Tags: python, django

Apologies for the long post.I am trying to generate sitemap.xml for a basic django blog application with a few static pages. I am not sure why the error occurs. Note: I have already created a dummy blog post and it exists when I get the error.

I tried to look at the django documentation but found it too confusing. The tutorials online weren't much helpful either.

```
**Error:**
NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml
Reverse for 'post_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['post/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

**sitemap.py**
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from blog.models import Post

from blog.urls import urlpatterns as homeUrls
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()


class StaticSitemap(Sitemap):
     priority = 0.8
     changefreq = 'weekly'

     # The below method returns all urls defined in urls.py file
     def items(self):
        mylist = [ ]
        for url in homeUrls:
            if url.name is None:
                pass;
            else:
                mylist.append(''+str(url.name))
        return mylist

     def location(self, item):
         return reverse(item)

**models.py**
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

**urls.py**
...
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemaps import *

sitemaps = {
   'posts': PostSitemap(),
   'static': StaticSitemap(),
}

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': 
        sitemaps},name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),       
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), 
        name='post_detail'),
    ...
]

**settings.py**
INSTALLED_APPS - [
     ...
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'robots',
     ...
]


I am very curious to understand how I can solve this error.
Thanks a lot !
```

Edit1; Added in the url for postdetail.

Comment: Where is the url for post_detail?

Comment: @vijesh - I have udpated it in the post . but here you go. : url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

Comment: where is the redirection happens in the code?

Comment: Your approach of calling `reverse(item)` isn't going to work for URL patterns that have arguments. You can't simply call `reverse('post_detail')`, you need a primary key e.g. `reverse('post_detail', args=[5])`.

Comment: @Alasdair - thanks for your response. I tried your suggested approach and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, that is on comments section, from @Alasdair is helpful:

Your approach of calling

```
 reverse(item) isn't going to work for URL patterns that have arguments.
```

You can't simply call

```
 reverse('post_detail'),
```

you need a primary key e.g.

```
 reverse('post_detail', args=[5]).
```